# Повышение производительности Go кода

Tags: mysql, golang, производительность

Как я могу оптимизировать производительность Go кода?
ОС: Windows 8.1 x32-64.
Суть работы: приложение подключается последовательно к более 50 БД (локальных БД), копирует данные в `.temp` файл (потому что эти БД могут использовать другие приложения, а как мы знаем невозможно редактировать БД когда его использует другое приложение), считывает данные из `.temp` файла и записывает считанные дынные с БД в текстовый файл "query.txt".

Приметка: в БД может быть от 10 строк до 7 тысяч строк. На все это уходит секунд 6-7 на мощном ноутбуке, а если ещё и запускать на более слабых пк/ноутбуках то может занять более 25 сек.

Код:

```
func fileCopyProcedure(ptSource string, ptDest string) {
    sourceFile, err := os.Open(ptSource)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer sourceFile.Close()

    destFile, err := os.Create(ptDest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer destFile.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(destFile, sourceFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    err = destFile.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    sourceFileInfo, err := sourceFile.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    destFileInfo, err := destFile.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if sourceFileInfo.Size() == destFileInfo.Size() {
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}

func DB_Handler(path string) {
    var db *sql.DB

    err := fileCopyProcedure(path, "tmp.dat")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    db, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", "tmp.dat")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("select cr_value, fx_value, orm_value, speend_value, sc_source_value, datainfo, secure_only from cookies")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var sql_cr_value string
        var sql_fx_value string
        var sql_orm_value string
        var sql_speend_value string
        var sql_sc_source_value string
        var sql_datainfo string
        var sql_secure_only string

        err = rows.Scan(
            &sql_cr_value,
            &sql_fx_value,
            &sql_orm_value,
            &sql_speend_value,
            &sql_sc_source_value,
            &sql_datainfo,
            &sql_secure_only,
        )

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if sql_cr_value != "" && sql_orm_value != "" && sql_datainfo != "" {
            var cprInfo = fmt.Sprintf("%s   %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\r\n",
                sql_cr_value,
                sql_fx_value,
                sql_orm_value,
                sql_speend_value,
                sql_sc_source_value,
                sql_datainfo,
                sql_secure_only,
            )

            var hkInfo = fmt.Sprintf("%s\r\n",
                sql_datainfo,
            )

            wfile, err := os.OpenFile(
                "data.txt",
                os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600,
            )

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer wfile.Close()

            if _, err = wfile.WriteString(cprInfo); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            wfile, err = os.OpenFile(
                "opx.txt",
                os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600,
            )

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer wfile.Close()

            if _, err = wfile.WriteString(hkInfo); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

        }
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Как можно ускорить данные процесс?

Comment: *как мы знаем невозможно редактировать БД когда его использует другое приложение* "А мужики-то не знают..." Кто Вам напел эту ерунду?

Comment: @Akina DB Browser for SQL

Comment: А поточнее? с указанием точного места... потому как или Вы неверно перевели/поняли документацию, или одно из двух.

Comment: @Akina DB Browser for SQL сам выдал мне что Database is locked. Когда я закрыл приложение (которое на данные момент юзает БД) я смог редачить БД. Давай лучше вернемся к вопросу о повышении производительности кода.

Comment: *DB Browser for SQL сам выдал мне что Database is locked.* Так это он сам заблокировал БД. (знать бы нахрена...)

Comment: @Akina реально? опана, это может сыграть очень большую роль, если это правда) Ибо копирование файлов это длительный процесс, сейчас попробую без копирования

Comment: @Akina спасибо большое за эту информацию ) Рузельтат выполнения сократился на 4 секунды из 8 ) То есть в половину

Answer (score 0):

Если это "50 локальных БД", да ещё обслуживаемых одним инстансом MySQL-сервера, то тупо выполняешь пакет запросов (хоть кучей, хоть по одному)

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file1.tmp' FROM db1.table1;
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file2.tmp' FROM db1.table2;
-- .....
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'fileX.tmp' FROM dbX.tableX;
```

а потом командой ОС

```
copy *.tmp all_data.txt
```

собираешь всё в один файл.

Всем этим можно рулить, ясное дело, из чего угодно - в т.ч. и из golang.

Как это сделать ещё быстрее - я лично представить пока не могу.